# kubernetest,the sharing Volume by Containers in one pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I get a question about sharing Volume by Containers in one pod.

Here is my yaml, pod-volume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: volume-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: tomcat
    image: tomcat
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    volumeMounts:
    - name: app-logs
      mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/logs
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /logs/catalina.out*.log"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: app-logs
      mountPath: /logs
  volumes:
  - name: app-logs
    emptyDir: {}
```

create pod:

```
kubectl create -f pod-volume.yaml
```

wacth pod status:

```
watch kubectl get pod -n default
```

finally,I got this:

```
NAME         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
redis-php    2/2     Running            0          15h
volume-pod   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   5          6m49s
```

then,I check logs about busybox container:

```
kubectl logs pod/volume-pod -c busybox

tail: can't open '/logs/catalina.out*.log': No such file or directory
tail: no files
```

I don't know where is went wrong.
Is this an order of container start in pod, please help me, thanks

Comment: in bash script ```tail -f /logs/catalina.out*.log``` you cannot put * into this, for catalina try to change ```tail -f /logs/catalina.out```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case:

Catalina logs file is : `catalina.$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log`

And in `shell script` you should not put `*` into.

So please try:

`command: ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /logs/catalina.$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log"]`

Comment: I check this and got this below 

`
[root@master ~]# kubectl exec -ti volume-pod -n default  -c tomcat  -- ls /usr/local/tomcat/logs

catalina.2019-10-23.log              localhost_access_log.2019-10-23.txt
host-manager.2019-10-23.log          manager.2019-10-23.log
localhost.2019-10-23.log
`

Comment: I take you suggest, and i got this : tail: can't open '/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
tail: no files

Comment: just adjusted the anwser !

Comment: Thanks,it works. 
Also, `command: ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /logs/catalina.*.log"]` works